# Solve $\int\frac{\sqrt{(x-5)(x+3)}}{(x-1)(x^2-25)}\ dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have some problems with the task. How to evaluate
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{(x-5)(x+3)}}{(x-1)(x^2-25)}\ \mathrm{d}x$$
I have absolutely no idea. Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please confirm the correctness of the edit

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge3,$

$$\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{x-5}=\sqrt{(x+3)(x-5)}=\sqrt{x^2-2x-15}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4^2}$$

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), start with $x-1=4\sec\theta$

Comment: and how it can help me?!

Comment: change of variable

Comment: @user151833, Simplify and find where you have reached

Comment: I did not understand :(

Comment: @user151833, Why don't you simplify?